# python 3.6 pynput NameError: name 'keyboard' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, pynput

I wanted to detect keyboard with pynput, so I copied and pasted a demo from their site.
Here it is:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

But I get this error, the file is named differently than the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Documents\Python\123.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput import keyboardFile
  "C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pynput.py", line 10, in <module>
    with keyboard.Listener(NameError: name 'keyboard' is not defined
```

Comment: did you install `pynput` (`pip install pynput`) ?

Comment: Yes, I opened Powershell and typed in: py -m pip install pynput.

Comment: Open your CMD, and type `pip install pynput`. What does it returns ?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied and a directory.

Comment: But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing a different *pynput*, file `C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pynput.py`, probably your own. And that's where your error is.

Move this file out of your Python path.